# How to get subprocess.Popen to work correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm trying get `subprocess.Popen()` to work correctly, but for some reason the returned value is completely wrong.

The script opens an FTP connection script that downloads files from a server, then returns a tuple of the successful and unsuccessfully downloaded files. This script has worked before using `subprocess.call()`, but I want to use `Popen()` so that the script it's calling is in another thread and doesn't interfere with the main program.

Here is my main class:

```
def FTPDownload(self):
    try:
        ftpReq = subprocess.Popen(['Python', mw._['cwd']+"dwnldMedia.py"],
                                  shell=True,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        successful, unsuccessful = ftpReq.communicate()
        self.consPrompt("Successful:\t"+str(successful))
        self.consPrompt("Unsuccessful:\t"+str(unsuccessful))
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        self.consPrompt((cp._['E0']).format(str(e)))
```

and here is `dwnldMedia.py` (`__init__` calls `download()`):

```
def download(self):
    #print("connected")
    self.server = FTP(**self.serverDetails)
    self.server.login(**self.userDetails)

    self.server.cwd("/public_html/uploads") #changing to /pub/unix
    #print "File List: \n"
    files = []
    successful = [0]
    unsuccessful = [0]
    self.server.retrlines("NLST",files.append)
    for f in files:
        if(f != '.' and f != '..'):
            #print("downloading:\t"+f)
            local_filename = os.path.join(mw._['cwd']+"media", f)
            with open(local_filename, "wb") as i:
                self.server.retrbinary("RETR " + f, i.write)
                #print("\t| Success")
                successful.append(f)
    for f in files:
        if(f != '.' and f != '..' and f not in successful):
            unsuccessful.append(f)
    return (successful, unsuccessful)
```

The output I get is:

```
Successful:
Unsuccessful:   None
```

Where `successful` has a value of `None`.

Comment: [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns the contents of `stdout` and `stderr` from the process — not what your `download()` method _returns_. In other words you need _write_ the values of `successful` and `unsuccessful` to `sys.stdout`. One way of doing that would be to simply `print` them out.

Comment: I'd recommend you add a `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` if you expect any data through the error stream.

Comment: @martineau, please post your answer as an answer.

Comment: It's not "another thread", it's a subprocess.

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was like opening a new thread. What library could you use to open a new thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really had things working using [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), you might just as well just keep using it — since `call()` uses `Popen()` internally — so `dwnldMedia.py` is *already* being run as a separate sub**process** (what you called a new thread), so that aspect of code execution won't be changed by making your code call `Popen()` directly.

Whether you use `call()` or `Popen()`+`communicate()` the download will not occur concurrently (which I assume is your goal) because both wait for the script to complete execution before continuing. For concurrent downloading, you need multitask using the `multiprocessing` module. Since what you're doing is I/O bound, concurrent downloads could also be done using the `thread` and/or `threading` modules (where it is often simpler to share data because it's all within the same process).

With that said, so this is actually an answer to your question, here's how to use the results returned from `subprocess.communicate()` and pass data from one process to another. You can't simple `return` results from one process to another because they're in separate address-spaces. One way to do it is to "pipe" the data between them. `communicate()` collects all the data received and returns it as a tuple of two strings when it returns, one for `stderr` and another for `stderr`.

The example uses `pickle` to transform the data sent into something that can be turned back in Python objects on the recieving end. The `json` module have worked equally well. I had to remove a fair amount of code from the examples in your question to make something I could run and test, but have tried to keep the overall structure intact in what's below.

```
import cPickle as pickle
import subprocess

class SomeClass(object):
    def FTPDownload(self):
        try:
            # The -u argument puts stdin, stdout and stderr into binary mode
            # (as well an makes them unbuffered). This is needed to avoid
            # an issue with writing pickle data to streams in text mode
            # on Windows.
            ftpReq = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', 'dwnldMedia.py'],
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            stdout, stderr = ftpReq.communicate()
            if stdout:
                # convert object returned into a Python obj
                results = pickle.loads(stdout)
                print('  successful: {successful}'.format(**results))
                print('unsuccessful: {unsuccessful}'.format(**results))
            if stderr:
                print("stderr:\n{}".format(stderr))
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exception:
            print('exception: {}'.format(str(exception)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = SomeClass()
    instance.FTPDownload()
```

and here's a stripped down version of the `download()` method in the `dwnldMedia.py` script:

```
import cPickle as pickle
from random import randint  # for testing
import os

# needed if not run in -u mode
#if os.name == 'nt':  # put stdout into binary mode on Windows
#    import sys, msvcrt
#    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

class OtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files
        self.download()

    def download(self):
        files = [fn for fn in self.files if fn != '.' and fn != '..']
        successful = []
        unsuccessful = []
        for fn in files:
            if randint(0, 1) % 2:  # simulate random download success
                successful.append(fn)
        for fn in files:
            if fn not in successful:
                unsuccessful.append(fn)
        results = {  # package lists into single object
            'successful': successful,
            'unsuccessful': unsuccessful
        }
        print(pickle.dumps(results))  # send object by writing it to stdout

instance = OtherClass(['.', '..', 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'])
```

Comment: I've tried using multiprocessing but instead of running the targeted script, it just duplicates my GUI window `ftp = multiprocessing.Process(name="FTP download",target=mw._['cwd']+"dwnldMedia.py") `
(Where mw._['cwd'] is the current working directory)

Comment: `multiprocessing` can be tricky. One of the rules of using it — that it sounds like you may not be following — is that the main script has to have an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard in it around the portion of code that represents the root process (because the main script is `import`ed by the sub-processes).